# How does postgresql.service know which postgresql instances to start?

Tags: systemd, postgresql

I've installed postgres 9.5 on ubuntu 16.04 which creates `postgresql.service` and `postgresql@.service`.

I understand that the `postgresql.service` spawns all enabled instances of postgres, and I can call a specific instance with `postgresql@9.5-main` but `postgresql@.service` is a template file, and I can't see any place where the instance string (represented by %i or %I in the template) would be passed by `postgresql.service`.

How does `postgresql.service` know which instances are enabled, and how does it pass them to the systemd template file?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To answer this, start with checking the contents of the two files in question. If you aren't sure where to find them, you can search the package contents for `systemd` files:

```
 dpkg -L postgresql-common| grep systemd
```

From looking at the `postgresql.service` file you can see you not doing much at all:

```
# systemd service for managing all PostgreSQL clusters on the system. This
# service is actually a systemd target, but we are using a service since
# targets cannot be reloaded.

[Unit]
Description=PostgreSQL RDBMS

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/true
ExecReload=/bin/true
RemainAfterExit=on

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

From the comments, we learn that the file is being used as a systemd "target". Moving on to the template file:

```
# systemd service template for PostgreSQL clusters. The actual instances will
# be called "postgresql@version-cluster", e.g. "postgresql@9.3-main". The
# variable %i expands to "version-cluster", %I expands to "version/cluster".
# (%I breaks for cluster names containing dashes.)

[Unit]
Description=PostgreSQL Cluster %i
ConditionPathExists=/etc/postgresql/%I/postgresql.conf
PartOf=postgresql.service
ReloadPropagatedFrom=postgresql.service
Before=postgresql.service

[Service]
Type=forking
# @: use "postgresql@%i" as process name
ExecStart=@/usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster postgresql@%i --skip-systemctl-redirect %i start
ExecStop=/usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster --skip-systemctl-redirect -m fast %i stop
ExecReload=/usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster --skip-systemctl-redirect %i reload
PIDFile=/var/run/postgresql/%i.pid
SyslogIdentifier=postgresql@%i
# prevent OOM killer from choosing the postmaster (individual backends will
# reset the score to 0)
OOMScoreAdjust=-900
# restarting automatically will prevent "pg_ctlcluster ... stop" from working,
# so we disable it here. Also, the postmaster will restart by itself on most
# problems anyway, so it is questionable if one wants to enable external
# automatic restarts.
#Restart=on-failure
# (This should make pg_ctlcluster stop work, but doesn't:)
#RestartPreventExitStatus=SIGINT SIGTERM

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The interesting directives are:

```
PartOf=postgresql.service
ReloadPropagatedFrom=postgresql.service
```

If you aren't sure where find the docs for a `systemd` directive, you can check: `man systemd.directives`. From there, we find both these directives in `man systemd.unit`.

Your biggest clue comes when you enable the service:

```
sudo systemctl enable postgresql@9.6
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/postgresql@9.6.service → /lib/systemd/system/postgresql@.service.
```

### Putting it all together:

- The symlink is how `systemd` knows to boot up PostgreSQL 9.6 when the server starts.
- The `PartOf=` and `ReloadPropagatedFrom=` directives handle making sure that `stop`, `start`, `restart` and `reload` on the `postgresql` service end up applying to all the related installed PostgreSQL instances.

Comment: Perfect answer, I never actually tried to enable/disable the service and I should have.

Answer (score 2):

At least in newer versions of postgres there is a systemd generator script at

```
/lib/systemd/system-generators/postgresql-generator
```

It will start all postgresql instances that have a value of "auto" in their

```
/etc/postgresql/VERSION/main/start.conf
```

configuration. So no need to manually enable these via symlinks in `systemctl enable` or something like that. Just change the startup mode in `start.conf` and do a `systemctl daemon-reload`.

Comment: Sebastian Wiesinger is a King among men and my personal hero.  Thank you for this one!