# systemctl status postgresql.service not working as intended

Tags: postgresql, systemctl

System: Ubuntu 20/WSL
Check status.

```
sudo service postgresql status
```

or

```
sudo pg_ctlcluster status  15 main
```

Now I am pretty sure the status is online. But even if postgresql is online, if i do

```
systemctl status postgresql.service
```

It says

```
System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
Failed to connect to bus: Host is down
```

I am confused. It matters, because I want to use command:

```
sudo systemctl enable postgresql.service.
```

Related post I found: https://linuxhint.com/systemctl-ubuntu/  [How does postgresql.service know which postgresql instances to start?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/436802/how-does-postgresql-service-know-which-postgresql-instances-to-start/436845#436845)

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `systemctl`, the error say it:

> System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't
> operate.

You have two options:

1. Configure your system to use `systemd`
2. continue to use systemV init system (`service daemon status`...)

Comment: Your diagnosis is correct but I’m not sure those options are available on WSL 

Comment: @StephenKitt, AFAIK you can't change init system in WSL. So for the OP is available only option 2.